Failing to bind input from html to ASP.NET Core model
I'm trying to create an Order entity. For that I have created a model, controller and view, but when I try to write something in the view nothing gets transferred to the post method and I get ModelState.IsValid is false.
The error is

(Name of the field) cannot be null

However, I've entered everything needed.
using FindWorkWeb.DataAccess.Data;
using FindWorkWeb.Models.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FindWorkWeb.Areas.User.Controllers
{
    [Area("User")]
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public OrderController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _context = context;
        }

        public class InputModel() 
        {
            [Display(Name = "Title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "ApproximatedPrice")]
            public float ApproximatedPrice { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "City")]
            public string City { get; set; }
        }

        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Input = new InputModel();
            return View(Input);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputModel inputModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var order = new Order
                {
                    ApplicationUserId = user.Id,
                    Title = Input.Title,
                    Description = Input.Description,
                    ApproximatedPrice = Input.ApproximatedPrice,
                    City = Input.City,
                    Status = "Pending",
                    PaymentStatus = false
                };

                _context.Orders.Add(order);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}

@model FindWorkWeb.Areas.User.Controllers.OrderController.InputModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Order";
}

<h1>Create Order</h1>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"/>
        @* <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.Title" class="text-danger"></span> *@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        
        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        @* <span asp-validation-for="Input.Description" class="text-danger"></span> *@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        
        <input asp-for="ApproximatedPrice" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" />
        @* <span asp-validation-for="Input.ApproximatedPrice" class="text-danger"></span> *@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" placeholder="City" />
        @* <span asp-validation-for="Input.City" class="text-danger"></span> *@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}

I have tried a lot of things like setting up separate view model with fields which user is supposed to fill. Tried to use different @model in the view file. But now I seem to be stuck here for the past 2 days.

Remove all @Model. from asp-for attributes.

I tried it too, but it didnt help:(

I reproduced your issue in my side, then I noticed that the tag-helper codes doesn't work which caused the model-binding failure. Just like the screenshot below, it's still asp-for.

Then we can add @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers in the Create.cshtml, or create another _ViewImports.cshtml in Area. Then it worked in my side.

By the way, you have public class InputModel() in your Controller, which I'm afraid there shouldn't have () here.
